# CAS: service tickets for stand alone applications

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

How can I validate or lets say "use" a service ticket in a stand alone application? I get that the client in the case of a web application handles teh validation and timeout etc., but what do I have to do that desktop applications do "something" with the service tickets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service tickets are provided during the login process webflow. For a standalone application, you should certainly use the REST API: https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/protocol/REST-Protocol.html

Comment: Yes, I know. But I don't understand what the stand alone application is supposed to do with the service ticket.

Comment: First, the standalone calls the CAS REST API to login. Then, it requires a service ticket to be able to call a web service protected by CAS.

Comment: With web applications, the service ticket was only created for registered services of course. Since my stand alone application doesn't have an URL, how should CAS now which service my stand alone application is?

Comment: In a stand-alone application, you don't need service tickets, just to validate credentials via the REST API. The service tickets are only necessary if you want to call web services.